# How to insert paginated XML (plist) data into database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I'm getting bunch of XML datas from an external API.

It gives me all data paginated which has 20 records per page.

It also gives me total record count for each document.

I'm getting XML -in fact plist data- with `Typhoeus` gem, I'm converting it with `Plist` gem and I'm inserting them to database.

Issue is; I can insert first 20 records -which means the first page- easily. But how can I calculate how many pages per document has and how can I dynamically make queries for other pages?

Here is my controller and actions. It works for first page, but not other pages.

```
class Admin::VideosController < ApplicationController
def index


      @videos = Video.where(program_id: params[:p_id])
      @program = Program.find(params[:p_id])


    if params[:cmd]=="get_videos_from_outer"
        @page=1
        @fetch = Typhoeus::Request.post("URL", :params => {:commandtype=>"getprogramepisodes", :feedtype=>"plist",:id=>@program.kid, :page=>@page})
        @plist = Plist::parse_xml(@fetch.body.force_encoding 'utf-8')

        import_outer_videos(@plist)
        redirect_to :action=>"index", :p_id=>params[:p_id]

    end


  end
end
```

And here I'm instering data:

```
private

def import_outer_videos(plist)
  @total_count = plist.second.first['totalCount']
  if !plist.blank?

        plist.second.each_with_index do |t, i| 



                if @page==1
                   if i > 0
                   @new = Video.create(:thumb_path=>t['tnPath'], :vid=>t['id'], :title=>t['title'], :type=>t['type'], :kid=>@program.kid, :program_id=>@program.id)

                    end
                else
                  @new = Video.create(:thumb_path=>t['tnPath'], :vid=>t['id'], :title=>t['title'], :type=>t['type'], :kid=>@program.kid, :program_id=>@program.id)       

                end

        end
        @page = @page + 1 unless @page >=  @total_count/20 rescue 0
        puts "###############################    #{@page}   - #{@total_count}  ###############################"
          if @new.errors.blank?
          flash[:notice]="Videos has been uploaded."
          else
            flash[:notice]="No new video."
          end

      end

end
```

PS: I'm using MongoDB and Mongoid.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it on my own. Here is my solution for anyone who may need to do something similar.

```
def get_videos_from_outer(page=params[:page], kid=params[:kid], totalCount="")

        @videos = Video.where(program_id: params[:p_id])
        @program = Program.find(params[:p_id])

        @fetch = Typhoeus::Request.post("URL", :params => {:commandtype=>"getprogramepisodes", :feedtype=>"plist",:id=>kid.to_i, :page=>page.to_i})
        @plist = Plist::parse_xml(@fetch.body.force_encoding 'utf-8')



          @totalCount = @plist.second.first['totalCount']

          if !totalCount.blank?
            @totalCount = totalCount
          end
        import_outer_videos(@plist, kid, page.to_i, @totalCount.to_i)

  end
```

And the `import_outer_videos` method.

```
private

def import_outer_videos(plist, kid, page, totalCount)

         @totalCount = totalCount

        plist.second.each_with_index do |t, i| 
        # First page has odd data and here we're getting rid off them
                if page.to_i==1
                   if i > 0
                   @new = Video.create(:thumb_path=>t['tnPath'], :vid=>t['id'], :title=>t['title'], :type=>t['type'], :kid=>kid, :program_id=>@program.id)

                    end
                else
                  @new = Video.create(:thumb_path=>t['tnPath'], :vid=>t['id'], :title=>t['title'], :type=>t['type'], :kid=>kid, :program_id=>@program.id)       

                end

        end

        if page.to_i < (@totalCount.to_i/20) + 1
        page = page.to_i + 1 

        get_videos_from_outer(page.to_i, kid.to_i, @totalCount)
        else
          redirect_to :action=>"index", :p_id=>params[:p_id]
        end

          if @new.errors.blank?
          flash[:notice]="#{@totalCount} videos has been transfered."
          else
            flash[:notice]="No new video."
          end
end
```